# Статические свойства и методы mvc, ооп, php

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Не судите строго, Осваиваю ООП и MVC. Но столкнулся с недопониманием таких терминов как статические свойства и методы. Очень много статей прочитал, но всё равно не могу понять в каком случае лучше использовать статический метод, а в каком обычный метод экземпляра класса. Видел некоторые уроки в которых, допустим, при работе с таблицами CRUD реализуют статическими методами, а в другом уроке реализуют через экземпляр объекта и обращаются к методам через this. Запутался в итоге)

Да, я понял, что статические свойства и методы не относятся к какому-то определенному экземпляру класса, с их помощью удобно проводить какие-то общие действия для всех экземпляров класса (подсчет, объектов и т.п)

Comment: Хм, можно ли этот вопрос отметить тревогой `Невозможно дать объективный ответ`, за это предложение `каком случае лучше использовать статический метод, а в каком обычный метод экземпляра класса` или нет?

Answer (score 0):

просто статический метод/свойство может быть доступно через стрелку из экземпляра класса (если он уже  у тебя есть).
Но this использовать не сможет